# Cron work is not working

Tags: bash, debian, cron

I'm using debian distribution. I have a cron job in `/etc/cron.d/` directory, It's called `testuoju.sh`. It looks like:

```
34 * * * * bash /var/www/html/script/testuoju.sh
```

`testuoju.sh` file in `/var/www/html/script` looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
omxplayer -b -o local /var/www/html/uploads/testuoju.mp4
```

Ofcourse I modify the minutes everytime I try it... But It doesn't run.

Comment: `PATH` environment? `DISPLAY` environment?

Comment: Revise `bash /var/www/html/script/testuoju.sh` to `bash /var/www/html/script/testuoju.sh >/tmp/mylog 2>&1` to see why its failing

Comment: To add to @IporSircer comment. If you run `env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin SHELL=/bin/bash HOME=$HOME USER=$USER LOGNAME=$LOGNAME /var/www/html/script/testuoju.sh` does it work. DISPLAY and PATH are the two most likely reasons. At least using `env` means you will not need to keep editing the crontab, kicking the daemon, and waiting for the time to pass.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues with your `cron` job.

First, I doubt your sixth entry should be `bash`; it's supposed to be the user to run the job as (presumably your user).

Second, `cron` isn't really suited to run a graphical program such as `omxplayer`. It can be made to work, but you'll at least need to set `DISPLAY` appropriately (so it matches whatever you have when running your desktop environment).

Also, Debian's `cron` manpage mentions that

> In general, the system administrator should not use `/etc/cron.d/`, but use the standard system crontab `/etc/crontab`.

There are a couple of things to note here: using `/etc/crontab` is usually better than dropping a file in `/etc/cron.d`, and all this is intended for the system administrator. For user jobs you should really use the user's `crontab`, *via*

```
crontab -e
```

(as the user). The caveat concerning graphical programs still applies...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute path of the `omxplayer` executable, e.g.

```
/usr/sbin/omxplayer -b -o local /var/www/html/uploads/testuoju.mp4
```

or wherever it might be placed.